# How to Give Permissions for postgresdb to our localsystem or to db in server

Tags: java, postgresql

I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL db from my java program,I am getting an exception as

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname
>   and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

> Client authentication is controlled by a configuration file, which
>   traditionally is named pg_hba.conf and is stored in the database
>   cluster's data directory. (HBA stands for host-based authentication.)
>   A default pg_hba.conf file is installed when the data directory is
>   initialized by initdb. It is possible to place the authentication
>   configuration file elsewhere, however; see the hba_file configuration
>   parameter.

The [example table covers all](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html#EXAMPLE-PG-HBA.CONF).

My values from windows64bit machine with ipv6. This allows connection from all users from the same machine.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS        METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32        trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128             trust
```